# get the output of array in deciending order using php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

i have one php array
 and i want to draw output of this array in something like deciding type.
**Here is my php code**

```
<?php
$data = array('A','B','C','D','E','F');
$count = count($data);
for($k = 0;$k<$count;$k++){
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        if($key == $k){
            $datanew = $count - $k;
            for($i=0 ; $i<$datanew ; $i++){
                echo "X";
            }
        }else{
            echo "V";
        }
    }
    echo "</br>";
}
?>
```

**current output**

```
XXXXXXVVVVV
VXXXXXVVVV
VVXXXXVVV
VVVXXXVV
VVVVXXV
VVVVVX
```

**excepted output**

```
XXXXXX
VXXXXX
VVXXXX
VVVXXX
VVVVXX
VVVVVX
```

**insort** 
    after X no V

what logic i want to implicit to get perfect output.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you're happy with the following solution:

```
<?php

$data = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
$count = count($data);
for ($k = 0; $k < $count; $k++) {
    echo str_repeat("V", $k);
    echo str_repeat("X", $count-$k);
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

I used `str_repeat` to repeat the chars `X` and `V`. So you just need only one `for`-loop.

Output:

```
XXXXXX
VXXXXX
VVXXXX
VVVXXX
VVVVXX
VVVVVX
```

[**Example on Ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/KNb1Sq)

Answer (score 0):

Simple just add break in your code as below:

```
    <?php
     $data = array('A','B','C','D','E','F');
     $count = count($data);
     for($k = 0;$k<$count;$k++){
       foreach($data as $key => $value){
          if($key == $k){
            $datanew = $count - $k;
               for($i=0 ; $i<$datanew ; $i++){
                  echo "X";
                }
               break;
             }
          else{
            echo "V";
           }
        }
       echo "</br>";
     }
   ?>
```

And output as you wanted